# How to select records in date order that total to an arbitrary amount?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of fuel deliveries as follows:

```
Date        Time        Qty
20160101    0800       4500
20160203    0900       6000
20160301    0810       3400
20160328    1710       5300
20160402    1201       6000
```

I know that on April 1st I had 10,000 litres in the tank so now I want to select just the deliveries that make up the total.  This means I want the records for 20160328,20160301 and 20160203.  I am using Postgres and I want to know how to structure a select statement that would accomplish this task.
I understand how to use the where clause to filter records whose date is less than on equal April 1st but I do not know how to instruct Postgres to select the records in reverse date order until the quantity selected is greater than or equal to 10,000.

Comment: This is called Relational Division https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 1):

```
with d as (
    select *, sum(qty) over (order by date desc, time desc) as total
    from delivery
    where date between '20160101' and '20160401'
)
select *
from d
where total < 10000
union
(
    select *
    from d
    where total >= 10000
    order by date desc, time desc
    limit 1
)
order by date desc, time desc
;
    date    |   time   | qty  | total 
------------+----------+------+-------
 2016-03-28 | 17:10:00 | 5300 |  5300
 2016-03-01 | 08:10:00 | 3400 |  8700
 2016-02-03 | 09:00:00 | 6000 | 14700
```

The data:

```
create table delivery (date date, time time, qty int);
insert into delivery (date, time, qty) values
('20160101','0800',4500),
('20160203','0900',6000),
('20160301','0810',3400),
('20160328','1710',5300),
('20160402','1201',6000);
```

Comment: Thank-you this worked correctly.  The only issue is deciding how to make the "with" more efficient so I do not sum years of data.

Comment: @SimonWhite: Just restrict it to a reasonable time frame in the `where` clause.

Comment: @SimonWhite: Included the date restriction and fixed a bug

Comment: Yes I was thinking about adding a reasonable time frame. Thank-you for your help. This will work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a running total using a window function based on descending order of date and time, like so:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Time,
    Qty
FROM
(
SELECT
    Date,
    Time,
    Qty,
    SUM(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC) AS Running_Total
FROM
    fuel_deliveries
WHERE
    Date < '20160402'
) rt
WHERE
    Running_Total <= 10000;
```

The inner/sub query gets you the running total, but you then want to filter on it where the value is less than or equal to 10000.

Comment: This is a start but unfortunately this will not select the 3rd record because the running total is over 10,000. I need it to stop once the total is 10,000 or more.  Secondly the inner SQL would sum millions of records in real life when the fuel_deliveries table holds years of data. I was hoping to make it more efficient so that it only had to sum records until the total exceeded 10,000.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but you won't get it to "stop" at exactly 10,000 unless the sum so happens to be that. It is either going to result in being greater than 10,000 or less than that - unlikely it will be that exactly.

Comment: Yes it is highly unlikely that it will stop on exactly 10,000 so I want it to stop on the first record that equals or exceeds 10,000 so I know that I have all the possible deliveries that make up the 10,000.